# What programmer should do before getting help from Designer in Design Issue?

Tags: php, asp.net, jsp

My self as a Front End Developer, for many years I have resolved many browser and CSS related issues for Developers coding in ASP, PHP and XSLT.

I just want some Front End Designers and Developers to point out, which things to be consider when there is some Design issue in Programming.

Firebug is one option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Designers and developers often have a symbiotic relationship. In my opinion, all developers should have (at least) very basic design skills and all designers should know a thing or two about code. I don't mean that the two professions should be able to do the other's job; just that each should have a general idea of how the other goes about solving problems. Much of the animosity frequently seen between form and function comes from either side not understanding the other.

On a more specific level, a developer can benefit from knowing HTML and CSS in that they can see what the designer is doing and make revisions if necessary. Better communication will result in better products, and the two professions can't communicate without knowing the same languages.

Answer (score 0):

As a Front End Designer the key things that Backend Developers tend to not be aware of are:

- **Internet Explorer** can and will take totally valid HTML, CSS & JS and botch the most basic expected behaviors
- Develop / Test interfaces in (Firefox,Safari,Opera,Chrome,Arora etc.) first! then be sure to review in IE6, IE7, and IE8...
- Take the HTML, CSS, & ECMAScript Specs with a grain of salt.  "Guideline" often seems like the more appropriate term vs. Spec.
- You've heard many a battle of Div's vs. Table's.  Div's are great but sooner or later you will encounter a need to wrap something up in a table to stop browser X from wrapping your content when you clearly told it not to. It is ok to "give up" once in a while.

Thus as an end result you want to pass information along to the Developers that help clarify what they really need to know (and hopefully save them the frustrating steps along the way).

Although sites like *[A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/)* have great articles w/code, sometimes the solution gets lost in the story.

For dealing with bugs I recommend this [**Knol**](http://knol.google.com/k/-/web-browser-bugs/) which links back into **[this browser bug list](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/)**.

The Knol doesn't provide much info but it does provide an organized index to find what bug is causing you pain.

Otherwise for general info check out the various developer blogs.  [Snook.ca](http://snook.ca), [PPK's QuirksBlog](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/), [The Man in Blue](http://themaninblue.com) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Where I worked, 'Design' is anything image-related, and 'Development' is anything code related.
Designers work in Photoshop and sometimes an HTML editor, and Developers work from an IDE.

The designer can do HTML and CSS, but the developers often need to tweak it to work with ASP.NET (change input controls server controls as needed). The developers could probably resize or recolor an image if need be, but are not as fast as the designer. Designers usually do their work upfront and the developers do the ongoing work.

By your definition, I am between a front end developer and back-end. The separation of concerns is not always clear.

Evan Meagher is right when to say, "Much of the animosity frequently seen between form and function comes from either side not understanding the other." It is the same for any two departments that need to work together. A way that you can smooth over the animosity, helping your teams understand each other is to have them talk to each other before any fights start. Maybe you could have a lunch and learn, where front end developers describe what they do, and some nuance of a particular project, and invite your backend developers to do the same next week.